# What is background build in Qt VS tools

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-c++, qt5

Relates to [Error while using Qt in Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59326402/2945027)

I have the same error. Unfortunately I cannot still fix it, as Qt VS Tools for VS 2015 aren't updated. But my question is not how to avoid background build.

My question: **what is background build?**

Comment: Maybe ask this in [Visual Studio | Marketplace - Qt Visual Studio Tools - Q & A](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheQtCompany.QtVisualStudioTools2019&ssr=false#qna). It seems that The Qt Company is answering questions. Maybe, they even find it worth to add the answer to the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I believe you are running into the 32767 names for this.

Let me preface this by stating that 2015 may have been the last time I used Visual Studio or developed anything for a Microsoft platform.

Part of your answer is [in this discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/24513).

I believe the latest (or more current) name for "background build" is "live code compilation."

This is a resource robbing, highly annoying, syntax checking thing Microsoft thought would be great. It ranks right up there with [Microsoft Clippy](https://www.artsy.net/article/artsy-editorial-life-death-microsoft-clippy-paper-clip-loved-hate) as far as tragic ideas go.

Basically, as you type, visual studio tries to build your stuff, puts squiggles under errors and generally consumes a whole lot of resources.

If you are using that Qt plug-in to build a QMake project this can cause all kinds of hardship, especially when you have UI files that need to MOC compile and are in the designer modifying the .UI file.

Whatever version of Visual Studio I was forced to use for that project, the first thing I did was find out how to turn that off.

Qt appears to [not play well with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/318748/alway-get-background-build-failed-at-startup-of-vi.html) it seems.

Here is [a more complete description](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pragmatrix.BuildOnSave) if you happen to have the plug-in.

> BuildOnSave is an extension for Visual Studio 2019 and 2017 that
> builds the current solution as soon a file is saved, and in
> combination with the the extension SaveAllTheTime, enables a live,
> background build experience while you type.

Comment: It do not think this is it, because: (1) it only happens on opening solution, not later (2) it started to happen with some update of Qt Add-in, as VS2015 wasn't updated for a while. (3) disabling Qt Add-in fixes the issue.

Comment: What you described is __exactly__ it. I provided it in this link:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/318748/alway-get-background-build-failed-at-startup-of-vi.html

Comment: *This* link is it. But the other parts of your answer seem to relate to similar, but different issue. I don't observe background build after it happened on opening as I type or when I save.

Comment: Well, until you posted your comment I didn't have an accurate description of just what you wanted. At the very end of your question you said your real question was the definition of a background build. The other parts of the answer I posted were answering what you claimed your central question to be. As to not seeing it _after_ initial load that would be because it failed and Visual Studio remembered the build process itself was hosed. As the other answer eludes to, there is a tweak you have to make. No, I don't know the tweak. I don't use Windows. Default settings are wrong.